# Improve the speed of this string_agg?

Tags: sql, sql-server, string-aggregation

I have data of the following shape:

```
BOM -- 500 rows, 4 cols
PartProject -- 2.6mm rows, 4 cols
Project -- 1000 rows, 5 cols
Part -- 200k rows, 18 cols
```

Yet when I try to do `string_agg`, my code will take me well over 10 minutes to execute on 500 rows. How can I improve this query (the data is not available).

```
select
    BOM.*,
    childParentPartProjectName
into #tt2 -- tt for some testing
from #tt1 AS BOM -- tt for some testing
-- cross applys for string agg many to one
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT childParentPartProjectName = STRING_AGG(PROJECT_childParentPart.NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY PROJECT_childParentPart.NAME)
    FROM (
        SELECT DISTINCT PROJECT3.NAME
    FROM [dbo].[Project] PROJECT3
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[Part] P3 on P3.ITEM_NUMBER = BOM.childParentPart
    LEFT JOIN [dbo].[PartProject] PP3 on PP3.SOURCE_ID = P3.ID
    WHERE PP3.RELATED_ID = PROJECT3.ID and P3.CURRENT = 1
) PROJECT_childParentPart ) PROJECT3
```

Comment: We need to see an execution plan for any performance related questions. (Paste The Plan)

Comment: That subquery has a big code smell. Why `LEFT JOIN`s when you require the rows to have a non-`NULL` value? Why `DISTINCT`? Can the same value of `NAME` appear more than once in the table `PROJECT`? If not is the `DISTINCT` required? Should the implicit `INNER JOIN`s actually be in an `EXISTS`? The (poor) performance likely has nothing to do with `STRING_AGG`.

Comment: The DISTINCT looks fishy and since you add WHERE clauses on P3 and PP3 be aware that your left joins are actually inner joins.

Comment: @Larnu Could you please take a rough swag at redoing what I have done, I would like to follow along.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The subquery (within a subquery) you have has a code "smell" to it that it's been written with intention, but not correctly.

Firstly you have 2 `LEFT JOIN`s in the subquery, however, both the tables aliased as `P3` and `PP3` are required to have a non-`NULL` value; that is *impossible* if no related row is found. This means the `JOIN`s are implicit `INNER JOIN`s.

Next you have a `DISTINCT` against a single column when `SELECT`ing from *multiple* tables; this seems wrong. `DISTINCT` is *very* expensive and the fact you are using it implies that either `NAME` is not unique or that due to your implicit `INNER JOIN`s you are getting duplicate rows. I assume it's the latter. As a results, very likely you should actually be using an `EXISTS`, not <strike>`LEFT JOINs`</strike> `INNER JOIN`s.

The following is very much a guess, but I suspect it will be more performant.

```sql
SELECT BOM.*, --Replace this with an explicit list of the columns you need
       SA.childParentPartProjectName
INTO #tt2
FROM #tt1 BOM
     CROSS APPLY (SELECT STRING_AGG(Prj.NAME, ', ') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY Prj.NAME) AS childParentPartProjectName
                  FROM dbo.Project Prj --Don't use an alias that is longer than the object name
                  WHERE EXISTS (SELECT 1
                                FROM dbo.Part P
                                     JOIN dbo.PartProject PP ON P.ID = PP.SOURCE_ID
                                WHERE PP.Related_ID = Prg.ID
                                  AND P.ITEM_NUMBER = BOM.childParentPart
                                  AND P.Current = 1)) SA;
```

Comment: This is quite literally hundreds of times faster, if not more. Thank you!